# UIKit Animating different views from one view controller to another view controller

Tags: swift, animation, uikit, uistackview, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm currently working on creating an animation in UIKit, and I'd like to explain my goal.

In my first view controller, I have a layout that includes a horizontal stack view and an image view.

When a user taps on a cell, I'd like to create an animation where the image smoothly expands and moves to the second view controller. Simultaneously, I want the horizontal stack view from the first view controller to smoothly transition into a vertical stack view on the second view controller. Additionally, I'd like to incorporate a smooth zoom-in transition to the next view controller screen.

How can I go about creating this animation?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var container: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.spacing = 5
        stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        stackView.backgroundColor = .black.withAlphaComponent(0.35)
        return stackView
    }()

    let elements: [String] = ["❤️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        elements.forEach { emoji in
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = emoji
            container.addArrangedSubview(label)
        }

        view.addSubview(container)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            container.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            container.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
            container.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: container.intrinsicContentSize.width),
            container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            container.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            container.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
        container.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    @objc func tap() {
        let animationController = AnimationController()
        animationController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen

        self.present(animationController, animated: true)
    }
}

class AnimationController: UIViewController {
    var transitionStackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 5
        stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return stackView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .gray.withAlphaComponent(0.45)
        view.addSubview(transitionStackView)

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissController))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            transitionStackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            transitionStackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
            transitionStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: -50), // Initial position above the screen
        ])
        
    }

    @objc func dismissController() {
        // Dismiss the view controller when tapped
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could mock-up some images of ***how*** you want the animation to look. For example, is this close to what you have in mind? https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f0qn.gif